# How to join 2 pandas time series

Tags: python, pandas

I have one dataframe of prices (df1) like this:

```
                        price
2007-01-01 00:00:00  0.789510
2007-01-01 04:00:00  0.789380
2007-01-01 20:00:00  0.789485
2007-01-02 01:00:00  0.791290
2007-01-02 02:00:00  0.791630
2007-01-02 16:00:00  0.793100
2007-01-02 17:00:00  0.793605
2007-01-03 18:00:00  0.780640
2007-01-03 19:00:00  0.780005
2007-01-03 20:00:00  0.779410
```

And one series of closing prices (s1) like this:

```
2007-01-01 15:00:00    0.7882
2007-01-02 15:00:00    0.7962
2007-01-03 15:00:00    0.7909
2007-01-04 15:00:00    0.7862
2007-01-05 15:00:00    0.7787
2007-01-08 15:00:00    0.7812
2007-01-09 15:00:00    0.7800
2007-01-10 15:00:00    0.7769
```

I'd like to add the closing prices from s1 to df1 so that the index of df1 is maintained and for each datetime stamp in df1 the latest possible closing price is added from s1.

So the resulting dataframe would look like:

```
                        price  closing_price
2007-01-01 00:00:00  0.789510        0.7882
2007-01-01 04:00:00  0.789380        0.7882
2007-01-01 20:00:00  0.789485        0.7962
2007-01-02 01:00:00  0.791290        0.7962
2007-01-02 02:00:00  0.791630        0.7962
2007-01-02 16:00:00  0.793100        0.7909
2007-01-02 17:00:00  0.793605        0.7909
2007-01-03 18:00:00  0.780640        0.7862
2007-01-03 19:00:00  0.780005        0.7862
2007-01-03 20:00:00  0.779410        0.7862
```

Comment: import pandas as pd; pd.concat([df1,s1]);  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I think that would just add the series to the end of the dataframe

Comment: Ah, I understand the problem better with the result there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really a 'join' problem but a 're-indexing' problem. pandas supports this and can do this in one line of code. See below,

```
df1['close'] = s1.reindex(df1.index, method='bfill')
```

This yields,

```
                        price   close
2007-01-01 00:00:00  0.789510  0.7882
2007-01-01 04:00:00  0.789380  0.7882
2007-01-01 20:00:00  0.789485  0.7962
2007-01-02 01:00:00  0.791290  0.7962
2007-01-02 02:00:00  0.791630  0.7962
2007-01-02 16:00:00  0.793100  0.7909
2007-01-02 17:00:00  0.793605  0.7909
2007-01-03 18:00:00  0.780640  0.7862
2007-01-03 19:00:00  0.780005  0.7862
2007-01-03 20:00:00  0.779410  0.7862
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate the closing prices to your dataframe along the rows (axis=1).  You then need to fill forward the closing prices.  Lastly, filter out rows where the price is null.

```
s1 = pd.Series([0.7882, 0.7962, 0.7909, 0.7862, 0.7787, 0.7812, 0.7800, 0.7769], 
               index=pd.date_range('2007-01-01 15:00', periods=8, freq='B'), name='close')

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'price': {
  pd.Timestamp('2007-01-01 00:00:00'): 0.789510,
  pd.Timestamp('2007-01-01 04:00:00'): 0.789380,
  pd.Timestamp('2007-01-01 20:00:00'): 0.789485,
  pd.Timestamp('2007-01-02 01:00:00'): 0.791290,
  pd.Timestamp('2007-01-02 02:00:00'): 0.791630,
  pd.Timestamp('2007-01-02 16:00:00'): 0.793100,
  pd.Timestamp('2007-01-02 17:00:00'): 0.793605,
  pd.Timestamp('2007-01-03 18:00:00'): 0.780640,
  pd.Timestamp('2007-01-03 19:00:00'): 0.780005,
  pd.Timestamp('2007-01-03 20:00:00'): 0.779410}})

df = pd.concat([df1, s1], axis=1)
df.close.ffill(inplace=True)
df = df[~df.price.isnull()]
>>> df
                        price   close
2007-01-01 00:00:00  0.789510     NaN
2007-01-01 04:00:00  0.789380     NaN
2007-01-01 20:00:00  0.789485  0.7882
2007-01-02 01:00:00  0.791290  0.7882
2007-01-02 02:00:00  0.791630  0.7882
2007-01-02 16:00:00  0.793100  0.7962
2007-01-02 17:00:00  0.793605  0.7962
2007-01-03 18:00:00  0.780640  0.7909
2007-01-03 19:00:00  0.780005  0.7909
2007-01-03 20:00:00  0.779410  0.7909
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander, unfortunately my real df1 contains a lot of NaNs before concatenation....along with a lot of datetimes at 15:00:00, so I don't think this solution would quite work as I'd like